# kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.16

Tags: package-management, kernel, ppa

For years I have used kernels from this PPA, but now with kernels 4.16.4 and kernels 4.16.5 I am unable to install (and also uninstall) broken kernel packages.

Distro is Ubuntu MATE 16.04 (Xenial).

Looks like some helpers not found on installation of kernel package:

```
linux-update-symlinks
linux-check-removal
```

There is also an unusual kernel package name which contains 'unsigned':

```
linux-image-unsigned-4.16.5-041605-generic
```

What is going on?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what is going on but I managed to remove the unsigned kernels by commenting out the line:

```
linux-check-removal $version
```

in the files

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.16.5-041605-generic.prerm
```

and / or

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-4.16.4-041604-generic.prerm
```

and then continuing with `apt-get` standard removal procedure (`ukuu-gtk` also works fine).

Comment: I did the same about removal.
But installation...  I found needed scripts in debian package linux-base_4.5. Now I am looking for same ubuntu package. Strange thing is that this never happened before 4.16.4

Comment: This is a clue  from ubuntu package search:
Exact hits
Package linux-base
trusty (14.04LTS) (kernel): Linux image base package  3.5ubuntu4: all
xenial (16.04LTS) (kernel): Linux image base package 4.0ubuntu1: all
artful (kernel): Linux image base package 4.5ubuntu1: all
bionic (kernel): Linux image base package 4.5ubuntu1: all

Now is the question am I safe to upgrade to 4.5  on xenial?

Comment: Confirmed!
After installation of package:
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-base/linux-base_4.5ubuntu1_all.deb
I am able to install and uninstall both 4.16.4 and 4.16.5

Comment: ...and it works:
$ uname -a
Linux hpEliteLin 4.16.5-041605-generic #201804260630 SMP Thu Apr 26 10:32:51 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Still don't know what is the meaning of 'unsigned', especially because  it appears in just few architectures.

Comment: 'unsigned' kernels are not signed with EFI/UEFI keys. However, I tried to boot these unsigned kernels in unsafe mode on my ASUS z170 pro gaming with an Intel i5 6600k but I still get a kernel panic. I'll try to upgrade the BIOS and see what happens.

Comment: Aha. EFI/UEFI. Thats's the answer. Well, I don't use EFI/UEFI and on 4 my machines (laptops, desktops) unsigned kernel 4.16.5 run just fine after I solved installation issue with Linux image base package.

Comment: No change after upgrading to latest BIOS with or without EFI/UEFI. Updated to the newest linux-base but still no change.

Comment: I used ukuu to install 4.16.5 kernel, which failed, complaining about not finding linux-modules-4.16.5-041605-generic_4.16.5-041605.201804260630_amd64.deb and after a manual install of this file followed by apt-get -f install, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I just `rm`'d the 1st script it complained about then ran

```
dpkg -r ${pkg}
```

then `rm`'d the 2nd script it complained about and re-ran:

```
dpkg -r ${pkg}
```

then I was able to successfully remove the unsigned kernel package.

In my case **${pkg}** was **linux-image-unsigned-4.16.5-041605-generic_4.16.5-041605.201804260630_amd64.deb**

(Disclaimer: This worked for me. I install my latest kernels with dpkg.  Try at your own risk!)

Comment: Dangerous... be careful